# How to use another column as login name when using FOS in Symfony2

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

I've installed FOS, and hooked it to my entity "Merchant" that I have created.

The Merchant entity contains a password but also 2 different ids associated to the user. I would like to get the user to be able connect using one id or the other, in the same field on the form.

Right now all I have in the database is my entity, and some fields that were added to it by FOS (username, username canonical, etc.)

What do I need to overwrite to make this possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this by implementing your own user provider. Create a class implementing the interface "Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserProviderInterface". In the "loadUserByUsername" method you can implement a logic that finds the user considering both IDs. Last but not least register your provider as a service and activate it in your security.yml.

```
# app/config/security.yml
security:

# ...

    providers:
        fos_userbundle:
            id: your_bundle.user_provider.your_provider # id of your service
```